# Insert into subquery condition

Tags: mysql, select, insert-into

I have this query

```
INSERT INTO subitems_detail (groepid, filiaalid, subitemsid)
SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT id FROM prijsgroepen), 0, subitems.id FROM subitems;
```

How can I create a condition that `MySQL` only inserts rows when `prijsgroepen.id` is **not** `1`?

I tried something like this, but the database inserts the rows anyway and assigns `0` to `groepid`, while the table should be empty:

```
INSERT INTO subitems_detail (groepid, filiaalid, subitemsid)
SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT id FROM prijsgroepen WHERE id != 1), 0, subitems.id FROM subitems;
```

Comment: is there a relationship between prijsgroepen and subitems? possibly a foreign key?

Comment: @BrianCohan, No, they are completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO subitems_detail (groepid, filiaalid, subitemsid)
SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT id FROM prijsgroepen) As groepid, 0, subitems.id 
FROM subitems
HAVING greopid <> 1
;
```

This assumes there is only one row in `prijsgroepen`; otherwise I am pretty sure the query would break anyway.

The subquery *might* be more useful as `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM prijsgroepen WHERE id != 1` and adjusting the HAVING to `HAVING greopid = 0`

For a set of subitems for each non-one prijsgroepen.id:

```
INSERT INTO subitems_detail (groepid, filiaalid, subitemsid)
SELECT DISTINCT prijsgroepen.id, 0, subitems.id 
FROM prijsgroepen, subitems
WHERE prijsgroepen.id <> 1
   AND prijsgroepen.id NOT IN (SELECT groepid FROM subitems_detail)
;
```

the `AND` line is optional to prevent duplicating previously handled prijsgroepen.id values.

Comment: `prijsgroepen` will contain more than one row :/

Comment: @DeMama see edit, might help or point in a general direction.

Comment: While this works if `prijsgroepen` only contains one row with id `1`, it doesn't work if other rows are added to `prijsgroepen` (eg id 5, 77, ..). It won't insert rows for the "allowed" ID's.

Comment: @DeMama are you only wanting rows inserted if prijsgroepen is empty?

Comment: No, I need rows to be inserted when `prijsgroepen.id` is higher than `1`.

Comment: So you want a copy of every row in `subitems` for every id in `prijsgroepen` that is not 1?